# jQuery scope, .each

Tags: jquery, each

More help, different issue.  I want to return allLessonsArray from the inner loops, but for some reason it doesn't reach outside the loop function.  I've noted where it works, and where it doesn't work.  How do I return this to the outside?

```
var allLessonsArray= new Array();
$.each(lessonInTopicSectionArray, function(index, lesson){       
    var lastAttempt = 0;
    url='domain/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id='+lesson.id+'&action=reportdetail&userid='+userid+'&try='+lastAttempt;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var lessonArray= new Array();
        $(data).find('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0')
        .each(function(index, content) {
            var string=jQuery(content).html()
            score=parseInt(string.substr(string.length - 1));
            lessonArray[index]=score;   
        }); 
        allLessonsArray[index]={name:lesson.name, score: lessonArray};
        //This works.
        alert(allLessonsArray[0].name);
        alert(allLessonsArray[0].score[0]);     
    });
    //This doesn't work.
    alert(allLessonsArray[0].name);
    alert(allLessonsArray[0].score[0]);
});
return allLessonsArray;
```

Comment: The asynchronous behavior of `.get()` is causing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get)*** is an ***AJAX*** ie. an asynchronous request, so you can't do that as you want.

You can do:

```
var allLessonsArray= new Array();
$.each(lessonInTopicSectionArray, function(index, lesson){       
    var lastAttempt = 0;
    url='http://www.training-source.org/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id='+lesson.id+'&action=reportdetail&userid='+userid+'&try='+lastAttempt;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var lessonArray= new Array();
        $(data).find('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0')
        .each(function(index, content) {
            var string=jQuery(content).html()
            score=parseInt(string.substr(string.length - 1));
            lessonArray[index]=score;   
        }); 
        allLessonsArray[index]={name:lesson.name, score: lessonArray};

         // check length to ensure that full array will return
        if( allLessonsArray.length === lessonInTopicSectionArray.length )
           reciever(allLessonsArray);

    });
});

function receiver(allLessonsArray){
  console.log(allLessonsArray);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the full array after the last iteration?

Comment: excellent.  Work perfectly, and I learned a new way to debug.  Thanks.

Comment: How would I return the array? (The code is from a larger function).

Comment: @NathanLothamer as `$.get()` is async. Instead of return you need to fire another function with the target array and make further process within that function. This is the process of return.

Comment: Thats what I figured, and that is what I'm implementing now, thanks.